# Type or namespace definition error

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm new to the forums and to coding, this is an error that I have not yet seen and as far as I can tell have enclosed my methods and classes correctly yet I am still getting the following 2 errors:

1. } expected
2. Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.

   ```
   namespace Assignment15Start
   {
       public partial class GradebookForm : Form
       {
           private Student betty;

           public GradebookForm()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           private void addStudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               betty = new Student() {Name = "Lisa", Id = 55555};
               //betty.SingleCourse.AssignmentCreate();

               private void Grade()
               {
                   double grade;
                   grade = betty.SingleCourse.CalcGrade()*100;
                   MessageBox.Show("Your grade is " + grade);
               }
            }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the `Grade()` method inside the `addStudentButton_Click` method.

You can't do that; methods cannot be nested.  (except for anonymous methods)